# WPF ListView isn't updated when the binded List<T> collection is modified?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

Is this normal? Do I have to call a method to force updates?

Basically I am adding new items and can see the list is growing in memory but the UI still shows the initial elements that was defined on startup.

Comment: This answers your question, as it did mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726665/why-does-an-ienumerablet-require-a-call-to-tolist-to-update-the-listview/3726843#3726843

Comment: Thanks man, it's a long question, answers, but seems like it has good info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a `List<T>` try using an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead.  An ObservableCollection has events that WPF will bind to to know when the collection has changed.  A regular List doesn't have this, so WPF doesn't know when things are added or removed.

Comment: Thanks CG, another question: can I also modify items inside an ObservableCollection? so like: collection[0].Name = "Cool"?

Comment: Only if your object implements INotifyPropertyChanged, which does the same basic thing.  It provides an event that WPF can bind to so that it can be notified when a property on an instance has changed.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Lastly why is it called ObservableCollection? ObservableCollection sounds like it's meant to be read-only, not to be modified, as in just observe.

Comment: I imagine it's because the events make it possible for a subscriber to "Observe" the behavior of the collection.  But I don't know, you'd have to talk to Microsoft on that one. =)